# File input with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [krajee bootstrap file input plugin](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input-ajax-demo/1) , but I have one problem.

When I browse to select one or more files and I submit the form, it works perfect, it uploads every file. But when I browse to select one or more files, then browse again to select another file and I submit the form, it only uploads the last selected file. Any suggestions?

My code is :

```
<input id="input-700" name="kartik-input-700[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading" data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="true">

<script>
$("#input-700").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "http://localhost/file-upload-batch/2", // server upload action
    uploadAsync: true,
    allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif"],
    allowedFileTypes: ["image"],
    maxFileSize: 5000,
    dropZoneEnabled: false,
    maxFileCount: 6,
    validateInitialCount: true
});
</script>
```

Comment: The file will get overwritten, What if there are multiple file type input's? will the plugin handle?

Comment: I suppose. Have you any idea how to solve it?

Comment: When will the plugin start uploading, Yes I have a plan, But i need to be clear on few things first

Comment: I didn't try it. Because I need it only to upload images.

Comment: Can you tel me when exactly will the plugin start uploading the images?? as soon as you elect it?? or you need to trigger the upload?

Comment: I have a form with a few more inputs. And when I submit the form then the plugin should be triggered. I can upload all code if it would be easier.

Comment: What if the user wants to remove his selection of images? What I would suggest is once the user uploads images to one of the file input, dynamically add another input and apply plugin to it, This way user willbe able to delete edit or add as many slections as he want

Comment: I would like to use it on this way. What you suggest is not a multiple upload.

Comment: ok then you can maintain all the uploaded files in a variable and clear up the input, And when you are submitting the form you can add up all these files into the input element